# why i cant take one float and one Boolean variable to convert gallons to letre

Tags: java

// convert gallons to leter

```
class galtolit
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
      double liter;// if this variable is float it throws incompatible type error 
                  // why i can't take float?              
      double gallons =10;
      liter= gallons * 3.7854;
      System.out.println(gallons + "  gallons = "+ liter+"  liter");
    }   
}
```

Comment: Where is the `Boolean`?

Comment: if i take boolean at the place of double

Comment: @kpv: ......why would you do that? `boolean`s and `double`s are fundamentally different.

Answer (score 2):

> if this variable is float it throws incompatible type error 
>   why i can't take float?

Because you can't take a `double` value and downgrade it to a `float` without an explicit conversion, because you'd lose precision in the process. Remember: `float` is a 32-bit IEEE-754 **single** precision floating-point value; `double` is a 64-it IEEE-754 **double** precision floating-point value. ([More in the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.3))

There's no reason to use `float` here. Stick with the `double`, which gives you greater precision.

Answer (score 0):

To convert the double to float, you will have to add "f" for type casting. See below:

```
class galtolit {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        float liter;// if this variable is float it throws incompatible type
                    // error
        // why i can't take float?
        float gallons = 10;
        liter = gallons * 3.7854f;
        System.out.println(gallons + "  gallons = " + liter + "  liter");
    }
}
```